# map over list of strings?

Tags: java, functional-programming, iterator

I tried to prepend to each string in a `List<String>`:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
List<String> prependedLines = lines.stream().map(line -> "." + line);
```

but get errors like

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that java.util.stream.Stream<R> conforms to java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

How do I prepend a string to each element of a `List<String>`?

Answer (score 6):

You need to collect your results:

`lines.stream().map(line -> "." + line).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Otherwise, the return type is a Stream of strings, incompatible with `List<String>`

Comment: Is there a short way I can prepend to each line without having to import Collectors?

Comment: why would you not import it? It's the way Streams work!

Comment: you could add an static import such as `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;` to write only `collect(toList())`.

Comment: Absolutely, but it doesn't change the fact that Collectors is actually a compulsory import to collect the result ^^

Comment: Actually there's a way not to use a collector, but it's clearly a bad example of Stream usage (so please don't do it ^^):  `final List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
  lines.stream().map(line -> "." + line).forEach(line -> returnList.add(line));` No need of a collector here, but I **really** don't see the point!

Answer (score 0):

Another way, very succinct, without using streams, that replaces the elements of the list in-place:

```
lines.replaceAll(line -> "." + line);
```

The [`List.replaceAll(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) method replaces each element of the list by applying the given `UnaryOperator`.

---

**EDIT:** In case you want a new list with the modified elements, you can simply copy the original list first:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(lines);
result.replaceAll(line -> "." + line);
```

And if you are on Java 10+, it's even shorter:

```
var result = new ArrayList<>(lines);
result.replaceAll(line -> "." + line);
```

Comment: This looks like it changes the list in-place. I need to return a new list w/o editing the one I operate on